# Launch two different scripts in two separate cmd windows using subprocess in python

Tags: python, qt, subprocess

I have a python GUI written with Qt using Python 3.4 as the current python version with two buttons. One launches a python script and the other launches a perl script.

The Perl button launches this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ipy64.exe", "qadriver.py", arg1, arg2], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Python button launches this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["perl.exe", "update.pl", arg], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

I'd like to click both buttons at the same time and see the output in different command windows. Currently the output from both programs is combined in the one window.

Is it possible to get subprocess to open separate windows?

Thanks,

John.

Comment: how are you seeing the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use start to do this

```
subprocess.Popen(["start", "perl.exe", "update.pl", arg], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Note that some programs like notepad.exe will open in a new window but it will not create a new cmd window.

You can test this approach with the following line:

```
subprocess.Popen(["start", "dir"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```